# Incorrect values coming from 4-20mA ADC receiver

Tags: pi-3b+, rpio

This is what I have.

- Raspberry Pi3
- i2c shield. https://store.ncd.io/product/i2c-shield-for-raspberry-pi-3-pi2-with-outward-facing-i2c-port-terminates-over-hdmi-port/
- 1-Channel 4-20mA Current Loop Receiver - https://store.ncd.io/product/1-channel-4-20-ma-current-loop-receiver-16-bit-ads1115-i2c-mini-module/
- Sensor that outputs 4-20mA.

My set up

- Raspberry Pi image with latest image
- shield on the GPIO pins of the RPi
- I2C cable between the Shield and the 1-Channel 4-20mA Current Loop Receiver
- I2C Cable hooked to the "IN" port on the Current Loop Receiver.
- I am using this example code.

https://github.com/ncdcommunity/Raspberry_Pi_ADS1115_16Bit_4Channel_ADC_Python_Library

Two things I found wrong with the above code is that it is written for Python2. The Rpi comes standard with Python3.

- I swapped out the "import smbus" for "import smbus2 as smbus" which says its full Python implementation of smbus. So barring that is the problem.
- The CONFIG_REG value was unassigned so I assigned it as "CONFIG_REG = list()" (after line 80)

Barring those two changing impacting anything...this is what is happening.

When I execute I get prompted for the channel.

For channel 0 I get numbers in the range of 198-205 when my sensor is hooked up, and 227-235 when there is nothing hooked up at all. Varying the sensor output doesn't seem to change these number. For example sensor will output 3.49mA when its in an "unknown" state. When it gets a good state it will output 3.98mA. When I increase the volume the sensor will go up to 4.9mA (based on a multi-meter reading it)
For channel 1-3 I get numbers in the range of 4200-4250.

I have validated with a multi-meter that my sensor is putting out 4ma (like 3.98mA) and then when I give it some load it will go up to like 4.9mA.

So my questions are:

1. If I hooked ground to ground on the 1-Channel 4-20 receiver roughly what values should I get?
2. Does the roughly 200 values give any indication What might be the problem?
3. Could my device be putting out the wrong voltage level on the 4-20mA? What should it be?

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: You are likely not using the ADS1115 module properly.  We need to see the code you are using.

Comment: It’s linked above. Haven’t confirmed it but I believe I figured out the issue. The module I’m using is designed for 2 wire 4-20mA, but the sensor I have is designed for 3-wire. Im ordering a different part and hopefully that solves the problem.

Comment: Show the code YOU are using!  You type a command at a terminal to execute a script.  What is the CONTENT of the script you are executing.

Comment: @joan It is linked above. Please see the link above in the OP for the code I am executing with the exception ls I listed.

Comment: No it is not.  What command do you type at the command line?

Comment: @joan python Example_SingleEnded.py